# Response with JSON stream in Slim Framework

Tags: php, json, stream, slim

I need somehow to make a response `->withHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')` from my API, but as i understood it requires stream in the response body. How can i turn my key-value array into the JSON stream and respond with it?

Now, my code looks like:

```
        return $response->withHeader('Connection', 'close')
                ->withHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache')
                ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf8')
                ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                ->withoutHeader('Content-Length')
                ->withHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
                ->withStatus(200)
                ->withJson($resp);
```

where `$resp` is my array. But it won't work...

Comment: Define "won't work"

Comment: @Devon either 500 Internal Server Error, either page not responding at all

Comment: Find the error message if you're getting a 500 response, likely in logs..

Comment: @Devon sorry, 500 was my fault, when `->withHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')` is there, Postman just complains that _Could not get any response_. When removing - works fine, but this header should be there somehow (requirement of the API i'm trying to deal with)

Comment: Remove "Content-Type" header, because it's already added by `withJson`.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#Directives)?